# Intellij Idea not supporting cpp files

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-ndk

I am trying to create an NDK application to test. I have already downloaded NDK and included in the application but there is no option to create a new C++ file, even the headed files like jni.h are not found. [I have also added an image of Intellij Idea.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8OzQ.png)

I have also tried to add NDK path in the local.properties file but it did not work.

Please help.

Comment: I think you need to use android studio instead.

Comment: I have tried Android Studio also but the result was the same.

Comment: Please follow the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#create-cmake-script) on a new project first and tell us if that works